# Upload file to Google drive (Owned account) in android?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, access-token

I am working in owned account google-drive implementation in android. I have to complete the authorization process (https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts), then trying to upload a file to Google drive. some of the tutorial using token to upload it. But i didn't know where to get the token_id from "Drive". I'm new in android development, so. If any idea for this, please let me know.

Thanks in Advance

I have tried this:

Authorization process

```
                  try 
                  {
                        System.out.println("HARDCODE CREDENTIALS here");
                           credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                              .setTransport(httpTransport)
                              .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                              .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                              .setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.DRIVE)
                              .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(tempPkc12File)
                              .build();
                    } 
                    catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
                      .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
                      .setApplicationName("Sample Owned Account")
                      .build();



 final File body = new File();
                body.setTitle("My document");
                body.setDescription("A test document saf hkfhflkhs;lkhlf h;ls;afhsa;lk");
                body.setMimeType("text/plain");

                java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("document.txt");
                final FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

                Thread thread = new Thread()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try {
                            File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
                            System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                thread.start();
```

Comment: But what is happening? Why doesn't it work? What's the error?